# New docx file --from original file and edited file by using python-docx

Tags: python

I’m gonna create an application that automates the process of revising Word documents `(both .docx and .doc formats).`

This application will be tasked with integrating content from a new text file into an existing Word document, employing the "Track Changes" feature to document every alteration made during the process.

The primary objective is to update the original document with new text—this includes deleting irrelevant text, appending new information, and modifying existing content as necessary.

I need some help.
  I have not yet found a way to proceed with Replace function while maintaining style during the development process.

Comment: I think there are such applications already, like MS Word, LibreOffice, OpenOffice... why reinvent the wheel? If you really want to write your own, please post the code you have so far. What happens when you run it, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask]. As is, your question sounds like you want someone to do your work for you, and this is not how stackoverflow works.